# Running 'rake assets:precompile' generates error: '`@application.css' is not allowed as an instance variable name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I'm working on a Rails 3.2 app, and I'm trying to test precompiling my assets for when I move my app into production. The app runs fine in development, but when I run:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
`@application.css' is not allowed as an instance variable name
```

I've searched my code, and there are no references to application.css, except of course the file of that name (and in an occasional comment).

I've also tried setting `config.assets.compile = true` in production mode, but that fails as well (the app server starts fine, but in production.log there are no errors, I just see the request, and Rails rendering a response, but doesn't finish).

Thanks for any help.

Here's a full trace when I run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`:

```
$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby /Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
`@application.css' is not allowed as an instance variable name
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:244:in `instance_variable_set'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:244:in `block in init_with'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:244:in `each'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:244:in `init_with'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:229:in `revive'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:183:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:7:in `accept'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:16:in `accept'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/node.rb:25:in `to_ruby'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:107:in `load'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:205:in `load_file'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:42:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/alb64/code/stc/reservations/config/environment.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:292:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:89:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/bi...]
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `sh'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in `ruby'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `ruby'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:9:in `ruby_rake_task'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:17:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:25:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/alb64/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

**Edit:**

Here's config/environment.rb:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)
require 'rails_extensions'

# Initialize the rails application
Reservations::Application.initialize!
```

And here's config/environments/production.rb:

Reservations::Application.configure do
      # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

```
  # The production environment is meant for finished, "live" apps.
  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"

  # For nginx:
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'

  # If you have no front-end server that supports something like X-Sendfile,
  # just comment this out and Rails will serve the files

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = SyslogLogger.new

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Disable Rails's static asset server
  # In production, Apache or nginx will already do this
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and javascripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Choose the compressors to use
  config.assets.js_compressor  = :uglifier
  config.assets.css_compressor = :yui

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to Rails.root.join("public/assets")
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )
end
```

**Edit #2:** So I've changed config.assets.digest to false, and now `rake assets:precompile` runs fine, but when I go to start the server (nginx + passenger phusion) I get the same error with the same trace:
`` `@application.css' is not allowed as an instance variable name ``

**Edit #3:** Ok, I've narrowed this down a bit further. It definitely has to do with entries in the public/assets/manifest.yml. I tested this by removing the first entry in the manifest (application.css), and the error changes to reflect the *new* first entry *application.js*. Still the same error, just with a new 'instance variable'.

Comment: What are the contents of `environment.rb` ?

Comment: Can I get a view of the application.js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the fault of your application.css file. The problem is with psych, probably because it is causing problems loading public/assets/manifest.yml, see this similar error on a braid commit, with a possible solution:

https://github.com/evilchelu/braid/commit/f08fac25570a1a56de8d6282f637d0604ef5e210

Try removing psych, or if that is not possible, look for the problem there. See this part of your stack trace:

```
 psych.rb:205:in `load_file'
```

You should be able to find a patch to psych which wil fix this if you want to keep it.

Comment: Thanks , you were correct. For the time being, I've replaced psych with syck.