# Error when deploying: '@asset_name is not allowed as an instance variable name (NameError)'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, capistrano, asset-pipeline, bundler

I'm using rbenv. I recently updated some gems including rollbar, rubyzip, database-cleaner, capybara and selenium-webdriver (which causes a bunch of other gems to be updated by bundler). Now I can't deploy (using capistrano). Here's the error, with some previous commands for context:

```
  * executing "ln -s /store/mysite.com/logs/rails/staging /store/mysite.com/rails/staging/releases/20130920190506/log"
    servers: ["server.mysite.com"]
    [server.mysite.com] executing command
    command finished in 172ms
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:update_code'
  * 2013-09-20 15:05:11 executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:assets:precompile'
  * 2013-09-20 15:05:11 executing `deploy:assets:update_asset_mtimes'
  * executing "[ -e /store/mysite.com/rails/staging/shared/assets/manifest* ] && cat /store/mysite.com/rails/staging/shared/assets/manifest* || echo"
    servers: ["server.mysite.com"]
    [server.mysite.com] executing command
    command finished in 391ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /store/mysite.com/rails/staging/releases/20130920190506; true"
    servers: ["server.mysite.com"]
    [server.mysite.com] executing command
    command finished in 934ms
/Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:292:in `instance_variable_set': `@AvenirLTStd-Book.eot' is not allowed as an instance variable name (NameError)
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:292:in `block in init_with'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:292:in `each'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:292:in `init_with'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:277:in `revive'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:219:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:20:in `accept'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:231:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Document'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:20:in `accept'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/node.rb:35:in `to_ruby'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:128:in `load'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/assets.rb:26:in `parse_manifest'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:191:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:191:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/assets.rb:93:in `block (3 levels) in load'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `invoke_task_directly'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:25:in `invoke_task_directly_with_callbacks'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:89:in `execute_task'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:101:in `find_and_execute_task'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/callback.rb:38:in `call'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:141:in `block in trigger'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:141:in `each'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:141:in `trigger'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:23:in `invoke_task_directly_with_callbacks'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:89:in `execute_task'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:101:in `find_and_execute_task'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/callback.rb:38:in `call'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:141:in `block in trigger'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:141:in `each'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:141:in `trigger'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:27:in `invoke_task_directly_with_callbacks'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:89:in `execute_task'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:191:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:110:in `block in define_task'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:234:in `block (3 levels) in load'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:56:in `transaction'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:191:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:233:in `block (2 levels) in load'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `invoke_task_directly'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:25:in `invoke_task_directly_with_callbacks'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:89:in `execute_task'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:191:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:110:in `block in define_task'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:201:in `block (2 levels) in load'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `invoke_task_directly'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:25:in `invoke_task_directly_with_callbacks'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:89:in `execute_task'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:101:in `find_and_execute_task'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:46:in `block in execute_requested_actions'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:45:in `each'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:45:in `execute_requested_actions'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/help.rb:19:in `execute_requested_actions_with_help'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:34:in `execute!'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in `execute'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/bin/cap:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/cap:23:in `load'
    from /Users/ilikepie/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
```

As you may gather, @AvenirLTStd-Book is a font we use. You may notice from the trace that psych isn't being used as a gem. The first time this happened I didn't have psych as a gem, but since then I had installed it as a gem (v2.0.1) and run `rbenv rehash` and I still get the same error.

There's a similar question on SO that suggests I replace psych with syck, but since syck is unmaintained I'm not comfortable using it in production. I'd rather get to the root cause of this. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the part of the generated asset manifest that Psych is barfing on? If you are using defaults, it will be in `public/assets/manifest.yml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Capistrano was one of the gems recently updated (to 2.15.5), and I noticed capistrano was in the stack trace. So I downgraded to the last known working version of capistrano which was 2.12.0, and now things are working splendidly. Before that, my stopgap measure was to add `YAML::ENGINE.yamler="syck"` to `~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/assets.rb:26`, similar to what is recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12211307/243500).